# GMAIL API PHP вывести письма, помогите разобраться

Tags: php, api, gmail

Не могу разобраться, как мне используя gmail API получить письма, открыть и вывести на страницу на PHP?

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Не могу найти готовых примеров в интернете

Почему-то все делают через imap или pop3. В принципе мне не важно как получить письма и вывести, главное чтобы работало. Подскажите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Строчка в composer.json](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/8865cab2efbd63b40f88552886865f31bd7f3edd/composer.json#L11), которая отвечает за "магию" появления класса "Google_Service_Gmail" из [документации на официальном сайте для разработчиков от Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php).
Чтобы отправить запрос на получение списка своих писем нужно воспользоваться методом API как описано [тут](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list).

Обратите внимание, что репозиторий, который вы указали в вопросе имеет readme.md файл. В нём собраны все нужные ссылки. Есть ссылки на документацию, есть ссылки на примеры, есть описание принципа работы.

Comment: Я совсем не понимаю как мне выполнить GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages на PHP?

Точнее я не понимаю где взять {userId}

Comment: Я прочитала, что нужное зайти сюда https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/getProfile?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D и нажать "EXECUTE"

Но эта штука не дает мне userId для того чтобы я могла удаленно на PHP через сайт читать сообщения с почты

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКорчагина userId - это параметр запроса. На странице есть секция **Path parameters**. Там в таблице есть описание параметра. Вот оно: "The user's email address. The special value me can be used to indicate the authenticated user." Вы можете указать значение **me**.

Comment: А как мне авторизоваться? Если я сделаю в PHP:
file_get_contents("https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users{me}/messages"); 

Это не сработает потому что нет авторизации

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКорчагина При использовании данного API необходима авторизация OAuth 2.0. [Тут](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) есть документация, которая объясняет, что нужно делать. Также обратите внимание на [базовую документацию](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) (конкретно на пример кода), которую я уже упоминал в изначальном ответе.